# String length according to a pointer?

Tags: c, string, pointers

I have seen in some answers here that it's possible to calculate the length of a string with a given pointer.

How can I know the a string length according to a given pointer in c?
Thanks!

Comment: You might like to have a look at [`strlen()`](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.24.6.3)? It takes a pointer to `char`.

Comment: The obvious answer is `strlen`, although that's *so* obvious there's some chance you're referring to some other issue that's more complicated.  What other answers are you referring to?

Comment: `char *ptr = str; while (*ptr) ptr++; printf("length: %zu\n", (size_t)(ptr - str));`

Comment: @machine_1: Doing `... %td\n", ptr - size)` would be even shorter.

Answer (score 1):

`strlen()` should do the job

```
char* str;
str = malloc(7);
strcpy(str, "string");
// The following should give you the string length
printf("%zu\n", strlen(str));
```

P.S.: And yeah, don't forget to add `#include string.h` for strlen() to work.

Answer (score 0):

here is a [cplusplus.org reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strlen/):

> char mystr[100]= "test string" ; defines an array of characters with a
>   size of 100 chars, but the C string with which mystr has been initialized
>   has a length of only 11 characters. Therefore, while sizeof(mystr)
>   evaluates to 100, strlen(mystr) returns 11.

so you can use strlen() function

Comment: This citation caught quiet some noise while copypasting it.

Comment: thanks for mentioning